# How to get the number of items in a Perl list constant?

Tags: list, perl, compile-time-constant

The documentation states that a list constant in scalar context currently returns the number of values, but this may change in the future. It also states that, to use a list constant as an array, place it in parentheses. So, what is the correct way to get the number of values in a list constant, and what am I doing wrong in the code below? I get the error:

```
Bareword found where operator expected at D:\Batch/list-const-error.pl line 5, near "@(INFOFIELDS"
        (Missing operator before INFOFIELDS?)
syntax error at D:\Batch/list-const-error.pl line 5, near "@(INFOFIELDS"
```

---

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use constant INFOFIELDS  => qw( filedate filetime filesize mtime filename );
use constant OUTTEMPLATE => '   A9       A7       A12      A12   A* ';
use constant NELEMENTS   => scalar @(INFOFIELDS);
my $line = pack( OUTTEMPLATE, @ARGV[0..NELEMENTS-1] );
print( "$line\n" );
```

Answer (score 3):

I know that you are specifically asking about a constant subroutine made with the `constant` pragma, and other answers have already noted that you don't need to the `@` around the return value of a subroutine.

The general way to get the number of elements in a list is to assign the result of a list assignment. Even an assignment to the empty list is good enough:

```
$ perl -le 'print $c = () = qw(a b c)'
3

$ perl -le '@c = qw(1 2 4 6); print $c = () = @c'  # but also scalar @c
4

$ perl -le 'print $c = () = 1 .. 37'
37

$ perl -le 'print $c = () = localtime'
9

$ perl -le 'use constant L => qw( v 7 ); $c = () = L; print $c'
2
```

If the thing supplying the list is an array (as it is in `constant`), `scalar` gives the right answer:

```
$ perl -le 'use constant L => qw( v 7 ); $c = scalar  L; print $c'
2
```

This works because you are asking for scalar context on `L`, which puts the last evaluated expression in `L()` in scalar context. The expression is the array variable that `constant` made to hold your list.

However, the `scalar` goes wrong in the (non-array) list case, at least for what people blindly expect. This gives the last element of the list:

```
$ perl -le 'print $c = scalar qw(a b c)'
c
```

Since many people use `qw(1 2 3)` as their input list when they try this, they accidentally get `3` and think it worked out. That's why I write so much about that in perlfaq4's [What is the difference between a list and an array?](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4#What-is-the-difference-between-a-list-and-an-array?).

Comment: I find it interesting that `perl -le 'print $c = scalar (qw(a b c))'` fails, too, while `perl -le 'print $c = scalar @{[qw(a b c)]}'` does not.

Comment: It doesn't fail. It does what it is supposed to do. The second one has an array (although anonymous) so it acts like an array.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the `@`:

```
use constant NELEMENTS => scalar (INFOFIELDS);
```

Comment: Or `0+INFOFIELDS`

Comment: Are the parentheses needed?

Comment: @U.Windl usually not, it seems

Answer (score 1):

A constant can be used as a subroutine, so you can call `scalar INFOFIELDS()` or `scalar &INFOFIELDS` to access the number of items in the constant list.

Comment: It should work as a bareword too as long as you've defined the constant already.

Answer (score 1):

Can also get your read-only variables (constants) as plain old lexicals, using another library

```
use Const::Fast; 

const my @constary => qw(one two);
```

Then use it as any other array to get its length

```
my $num_elems = @constary;                # or

const my $num_elems => scalar @constary;  # better as length is constant
```

or

```
say "Number of elements: ", scalar @constary;  # or 0+@constary
```

to get the number of elements on the fly.  Here [scalar](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/scalar) forces scalar context, in which an array is evaluated to its length (number of elements), and `0+...` forces numeric (and scalar) context.

Now there's no puzzle, use these lexical variables normally as any other. See [Const::Fast](https://metacpan.org/pod/Const::Fast). Its [code](https://metacpan.org/dist/Const-Fast/source/lib/Const/Fast.pm) is 74 lines.